# cout hangs on mouse click in console window

Tags: c++

This console program writes 'hello world' to the console window every second.

```
int main()
{
    while( 1 )
    {
        cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that when I click the mouse when the cursor is in the window, the display stops updating.

Why does this happen?

How can I keep the updates going when I do the mouse-click?

I am guessing that something happens when the console window gets focus, but I have no idea how to handle it.

Running on windows 7.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it.  If I take the console window out of "Quick Edit" mode the problem vanishes

Comment: You should mark this as answer.  Also a note, but it seems that doing it once in a console sets it that way across the computer. (tested on 2 unrelated c++ solutions)